# Getting file path in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am having a bit of trouble in obtaining a file path so that I can open and execute my data from the specified (text) file. Below is the code I have written so far:

```
def pickfile():
    options={}
    options['defaultextension'] = '.txt'
    options['filetypes'] = [('all files','.*'), ('text files', '.*txt')]
    options['initialfile'] = 'sample.txt'
    options['initialdir'] = 'C:\Users\profcs\Desktop'

    filename=open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options))
    if filename:
        print(filename)
        return 
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        try:
            for row in reader:
                print row
        except csv.Error as e:
            sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num,e))

but1 = Button(widget1, text='Pick Your File', command=pickfile)
but1.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=1, anchor=SE)
but1.config(relief=RAISED, bd=2)
```

When I display a filename, I now get the path in this form:

```
================ RESTART: C:\Users\profcs\Desktop\BD TEST.py ================
<open file u'C:/Users/profcs/Desktop/sample.txt', mode 'r' at 0x01EFF128>
```

How can I filter this path and only get `'C:/Users/profcs/Desktop/sample.txt'` so that I can open my file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`filename.name` gives you the path from `filename` object.

I hope this helps :

```
filename = open(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(**options))
print (filename.name)
'C:/Users/profcs/Desktop/sample.txt'
```

In your case `filename` is an object which represents an open file.